# The right way to add more padding to a bootstrap container

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, typo3, padding, scss-mixins

Scenario: More padding in container
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27KSv.png)

Hey, I use the bootstrap scss in typo3 and let ws_scss compile it.
I want more padding so the content area is a bit smaller.

Basic information:

- Typo3 10
- Bootstrap 4

Can I just add a class to the div with the container and override the padding?

eg. `<div class="container custom-padding"></div>`

Or is there a possibility that mixins and co. will not work in the future or will work differently?

**In short: Do i have to use the bootstrap spacing utility classes or can i use my own class?**

Thanks in advance :)

*(This is more of a personal learning question to avoid making mistakes in the future.)*

Comment: IIRC in bootstrap 4 the container padding is done halving the variable  $grid-gutter-width.
This will affect the gutter between columns.
Or you can adjust the $container-max-widths variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's vertical padding you might chose just to adjust the settings in a content element, or to adjust the classes that are given to the according settings:
[image]

Concerning horizontal padding you can adjust the classes according to these settings:
[image]

Bootstrap mixins are only available in the extension bootstrap_package and perhaps some other extensions, but not in TYPO3 itself, at least concerning the frontend.
In general you're free to use your own classes, but it would be a pity if the shown settings would break by it. Nevertheless, if you never use these settings you can hide them too, then you've no limits in CSS.

Beside these fundamental thoughts you can find perhaps extensions that can be easily adjusted to have a larger padding.
There exists a large list only with bootstrap related extensions:
https://extensions.typo3.org/?tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=typo3%3A10+LTS&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=bootstrap